# I am not able to use ecma6 import in my code getting error "unexpected token import "

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

here is my webpack.config.js code i am using for generating virtual bundle.js :-

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        devtool :'inline-source-map',    //this give us the line no. incase of error
        entry:[
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './src'
        ],      //this is where webpack look for the files
        output : {
            path : path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },   //this is where webpack create the virtual output

        resolve: {
            modulesDirectories :['node_modules','src'], //this is where webpack look for module directories
            extensions :   ['','.js'],  // this is the extension for which webpack look for

        },
        module:{
            loader :[
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,  //this is to for we can use jsx file if not js file
                    exclude: /node_modules/,  //the part which are not included in our app build
                    //loader: 'babel-loader'
                    loaders : ['react-hot','babel-loader','babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'],  // the module which are used to load our app
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins:[
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), //for live reloading
            new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin() // stop app to run if there is any error
        ]

    }
```

and let is working fine but these ecmascript6 keywords like class and import are not working.

webpack 1.13.1
node v6.3.1
npm 3.10.3

package.json

```
{
        "name": "react-todos",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "",
        "main": "index.js",
        "dependencies": {
          "react": "^15.3.0",
          "react-dom": "^15.3.0"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
          "babel-core": "*",
          "babel-loader": "*",
          "babel-preset-es2015": "*",
          "babel-preset-react": "*",
          "react-hot-loader": "*",
          "webpack": "*",
          "webpack-devserver": "*"
        },
        "scripts": {
          "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
        },
        "keywords": [],
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC"
      }
```

my code for index.js:-

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import App from 'component/app';

    console.log("hiii")
    render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like webpack is not *loading* your loaders. Looking into your webpack config file I see a possible issue that can prevent webpack not properly *loading* the loaders. Your module `loader` field lacks the ending `s`. Webpack expects a `loaders` field and you are providing `loader` instead that is being ignored.

```
module: {
  loaders: [
        ^
```

It is subtle but could be the cause.